# Routing. How do you transfer properties?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two inscriptions on my page. Clicking on the first opens page /event/1, clicking on the second opens /event/2. I pass the name of these inscriptions through props which is called 'title'. Of course, the title must be different.  How do I do this? For example, for /event/1 title, the title should be 'click me', for /event/2 -- 'click me too'.

Now it's called the same for everyone -- 'different titles'.

I need to pass props to a component called ShowCardDescription.

Help me, please

```js
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { BrowserRouter, Link, Route } from "react-router-dom";

class ShowCardDescription extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { isToggleCard: true };
  }

  handleClickCard = () => {
    this.setState({
      isToggleCard: !this.state.isToggleCard
    });
    this.props.handleClick();
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div class="main">
        <section>
          {this.props.isToggleOn && (
            <div className="element" onClick={this.handleClickCard}>
              {this.props.title}
            </div>
          )}
        </section>
        {!this.state.isToggleCard && (
          <div className="content">
            <div onClick={this.handleClickCard}>
              <p className="close">close</p>
            </div>
            {this.props.children}
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Description extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Name: {this.props.name}</p>
        <p>Time: {this.props.time}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default class MainContent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isToggleOn: true
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState({
      isToggleOn: !this.state.isToggleOn
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div id="tabs-content">
          {[1, 2].map(index => {
            return (
              <Link to={"/event/" + index}>
                <ShowCardDescription
                  idx={index}
                  isToggleOn={this.state.isToggleOn}
                  handleClick={this.handleClick}
                  title="different titles"
                >
                  <Route
                    path="/event/:index"
                    render={props => {
                      if (props.match.params.index === "1")
                        return <Description name="something" time="13s" />;
                      else return <Description name="something2" time="now" />;
                    }}
                  />
                </ShowCardDescription>
              </Link>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an array of objects{} gives more alternatives.
Since your index start at 1 and not 0, we can assign a custom index key
starting from 1.

```js
{
    [{key:1, title:"click me"}, {key:2, title:"click me too"}].map(index => {
        return (
            <Link to={"/event/" + index.key}>
                <ShowCardDescription
                    idx={index}
                    isToggleOn={this.state.isToggleOn}
                    handleClick={this.handleClick}
                    title={index.title}
                >
                    <Route
                        path="/event/:index"
                        render={props => {
                            if (props.match.params.index.key === "1")
                                return <Description name="something" time="13s" />;
                            else return <Description name="something2" time="now" />;
                        }}
                    />
                </ShowCardDescription>
            </Link>
        );
    })
}
```

This also allows to stuff more properties into the loop

```js
[{dates:'etc', etc:'etc', arr:[], obj:{} },..].map()
```

Answer (score 1):

For you to have different titles for each `ShowCardDescription` you need to pass them for each item in the array you are passing. The most straightforward way to do this in your code would be to change your array from `[1, 2]` to `[{title: "click me!"}, {title: "click me to!"}]` and then in you `map` function you would do like this:

```
{[
   {title: "click me!", prop1: "some other stuff", prop2: "some other other stuff"}, 
   {title: "click me too!", prop1: "some other stuff", prop2: "some other other stuff"}
 ].map((object, index) => { // Notice the function params
            return (
              <Link to={"/event/" + index + 1}> // Index still working and 
                                                // adding 1 to be the same as your answer
                <ShowCardDescription
                  idx={index}
                  isToggleOn={this.state.isToggleOn}
                  handleClick={this.handleClick}
                  title={object.title} // Notice I changed here
                >
                  <Route
                    path="/event/:index"
                    render={props => {
                      if (props.match.params.index === "1")
                        return <Description name="something" time="13s" />;
                      else return <Description name="something2" time="now" />;
                    }}
                  />
                </ShowCardDescription>
              </Link>
            );
          })}
```

Comment: Thats cool solution, but in your case, indexes will be 0 and 1, not 1 and 2. You should write `index + 1` everywhere or adapt other parts of the code.

Comment: original code didn't rely on the index of the items, but on the actual values (1,2). Better to pass an object with title and id, instead of just strings.

Comment: What if I have to transmit not only the title, but also, for example, place and date? Can I do it the way you wrote it?

Comment: Hey! I updated my answer to support objects in the array. You then use that like `object.title`, for example.

Comment: I'm sorry, why the error on this line? {title: "click me!", prop1: "some other stuff", prop2: "some other other stuff"},   Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "]"

Comment: You're either copying too much or too little. Check if you have everything well closed before this code, like function brackets or something like that. It's probably unrelated to this particular snippet.